# Tell me how to fill a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++

I want to manually fill the array, but I can’t understand what’s wrong.

```
int arr[0][4]{ 1,0,0,1 },
    arr[1][4]{ 0,2,0,4 }, 
    arr[2][4]{ 0,0,0,6 }, 
    arr[3][4]{ 0,1,0,4 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax for that:

```
int arr[4][4] {
    { 1,0,0,1 },
    { 0,2,0,4 }, 
    { 0,0,0,6 }, 
    { 0,1,0,4 }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, as I understand it, the = sign is not required, as in other examples.

Comment: @user correct. The `=` sign is not required by C++.

Comment: And can you give another example of a three-dimensional array if not difficult?

Comment: @user [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qvR9O-) is a 3D one